# Form submit call slow SQL Queries on ManyToOne

Tags: symfony

Since I added a lot of "cities" in my database, all my backend slow down on form submitting.
When I submit a form containing a ManyToOne field (here : city), Symfony perform a SQL Query :

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, .... FROM city t0
```

When I submit the request

```
$form->submit($request);
```

My entity is saved, no problem here. So my question is : Why do Symfony call a query without *where* conditions on a table with 40k+ datas ? How to avoid this useless query ?

For information, on

```
$form->getForm();
```

It call (as expected)

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, ... FROM city t0 WHERE t0.id = 392
```

---

My form :

```
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('receiver', 'form', $receiver)
        ->add('city', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'SensiCofcBundle:City',
                'required' => true
            )
        );

        $form = $form->getForm(); // Ok "Select * from city WHERE id=392"

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') || $request->isMethod('PUT'))
        $form->submit($request); // Slow "Select * from city"
```

My Entity :

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A\B\Entity\City")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
 * @Expose
 */
private $city;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Symfony perform a full sql query "SELECT * FROM entity" in order to fill the [select/radio/checkboxes] in the view.

In my case I populate my html elements by external ajax. So I used the "query_builder" parameter to display the same options :

```
        ->add('city', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'Bundle:City',
                'required' => false,
                'query_builder' => function() {
                    $qb =  $this->em->getRepository('Bundle:City')->createQueryBuilder('c');
                    $qb->where('c.enabled=1');
                    return ($qb);
                }
            )
        )
```

Hope this helps